# how to show file save/download file dialog box in java

Tags: java

sorry for cross posting question

hii,
I want to show or open a file save dialog box to save the file 
which user want, its a stand alone program
means user it self save file by selecting path from that dialog box
I m trying to do this with applet or Japplet
plz help me
give some hint or give some code to do that

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [FileChooser](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: thanks for suggestion 
I have used this code.

public static File openFile() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        return fileChooser.getSelectedFile();


but this take file form specified path
what is to used to save a file into a specified path
by clicking on to button.